# On click event doesn't work on mobile devices for dynamically build elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, createelement

This is how I build DOM:

```
var projectOverlay = document.createElement("div");
projectOverlay.className = "projectOverlay";
projectOverlay.onclick = function(){openSlider($(this))};   
project.appendChild(projectOverlay);
```

The `openslider(elem)` function works perfectly fine in all browsers except on mobile devices (Android phones, iPhone, iPad etc...) . Is there any other way to bind events to the yet created element or I am doing something wrong here?

Necessarily have a look at this link before writing your answers... [js/jquery speed test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-createelement)

Comment: Looks like you are mixing plain JS for `document.createElement` etc, and jQuery.  If you are using jQuery, then make use of its event binding.  Use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to bind onclick for current and future elements.

Comment: You already have jQuery in your project. Use it to create DOM and event handlers instead of doing it manually. And use event delegation.

Comment: @DCoder - How to use jquery to build dom? I read somewhere that native javascript createelement is far the fastest method? It takes like 5 times less to build the object than any other method... Right an example in answer please...

Comment: @Berkowski - Can you write an example how would you do it using on() method? please... I've tried that before , but couldnt make it to work... :(

Comment: Create an element (it's really a preference unless you're building huge chunks of DOM): `$('<div class="projectOverlay" />').appendTo($(project))`. Event delegation: $('body').on('click', '.projectOverlay', function() { openSlider($(this)); })`.

Comment: i am making a single page website, completely powered by jscript/jquery, so i build complete pages with js....

Comment: Ok...obviously i need to explain this better.I am making a single page website completely powered by javascript/jquery/json . Each page is built as a plugin. That plugin has an init method which among other things contains the function which builds the dom on the way i described in my original question.This is all really fast and  smooth, but onClick doesn't work on mobile devices (onTouch neither) for dynamically built elements,which are basically all except the nav which doesn't change.Event delegation doesn't work neither. Script -http://www.wheniamplaying.com/mmrApp/js/myLibs/projects.js

Comment: I think that ipad will only register click on <a> tag , but i can't test this before Monday, when i get to the office as i don't have an ipad with me atm... Can anyone tell me if i am right?